# Set a fixed focus value in the main camera (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera2

I am developing an app for my project and I don't want my main camera to have autofocus. I want my camera to have a specific focus value that can focus on objects that are about 5-10 cm from the main camera.

Here is the code on how the CameraManager is implemented:

```
private String chooseCamera() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
      for (final String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
        final CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

        // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
        final Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
        if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
          continue;
        }

        final StreamConfigurationMap map =
                characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

        if (map == null) {
          continue;
        }

        // Fallback to camera1 API for internal cameras that don't have full support.
        // This should help with legacy situations where using the camera2 API causes
        // distorted or otherwise broken previews.
        useCamera2API =
                (facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                        || isHardwareLevelSupported(
                        characteristics);
        LOGGER.i("Camera API lv2?: %s", useCamera2API);

//        manager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
        return cameraId;
      }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
      LOGGER.e(e, "Not allowed to access camera");
    }
    return null;
  }

protected void setFragment() {
  String cameraId = chooseCamera();
  Fragment fragment;
  if (useCamera2API) {
     CameraConnectionFragment camera2Fragment =
        CameraConnectionFragment.newInstance(
                      (size, rotation) -> {
                        previewHeight = size.getHeight();
                        previewWidth = size.getWidth();
                        CameraActivity.this.onPreviewSizeChosen(size, rotation);
                      },
                      this,
                      getLayoutId(),
                      getDesiredPreviewFrameSize());

      camera2Fragment.setCamera(cameraId);
      fragment = camera2Fragment;
    } else {
      fragment =
              new LegacyCameraConnectionFragment(this, getLayoutId(), getDesiredPreviewFrameSize());
    }

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first turn off autofocus by using CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE and then set desired focus distance value using this request key, CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE.

To know if a device supports manual sensor or not, query characteristics and check for support.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MANUAL_SENSOR